# Php exits silently after loading from composer loadClass()

Tags: php, composer-php

I am trying to load a trait in a class. This particular trait has been declared and use in a previous dependency without problems.

```
class Task
{
    use \ApiGoat\Api\Message;
...
}
```

Adding this use call makes php exit after composer's autoload function `loadClass()` (as per xdebug).

I am at a lost, there is no messages, no logs, no errors.

Any ideas?

Comment: What have you tried to debug the problem? Can you share more code? And please explain how this is related to Composer itself

Answer (score 1):

I figured it out! Somewhere in an included library from composer, there was an error_reporting(1);

This would kill the error reporting midway in the execution of the code... Took me a while. Thanks Nico Haase for trying to help. I figured it out trying to get you more info!